# Display FBDialog in correct size on iPhone

Tags: iphone, facebook, fbconnect

I am trying to display a connect dialog for facebook in my app. The dialog view pops open and loads from facebook. But the page shown is one for regular browser, not the version optimized for mobile phones.

Do I need to do anything with my app or on facebook for it to work? Or do I need to provide that form on my server?

Confused
JT

Comment: I think this indicates your API key/secret are not entered correctly. Did you get them from the Facebook Developer page?

Comment: 'Twas a problem with the session not being established correctly before I called FBDialog. Good pointer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure that the session is actually established before you instantiate FBDialog.